# How to modify data in the char dialog box instead of adding new column in the sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm struggling with a problem in MS Excel. I want to change the data used for a chart in the edit series dialog box instead of adding an extra column in the sheet with the modified data. For example, let's say in column A, I have 1, 2, ..., 6 and in column B, I have 1,2, ..., 6. Very easy, we can plot B vs. A. Now let's say we want to plot 2*B vs. A without making column C = 2*B.

Any insight is very much obliged.

Comment: You can work around the constraints of Excel using defined names or other approaches. But the easiest and most robust way to generate chart data is to via worksheet cells. A simple formula in a worksheet might consume an extra column, but it gives a very visual data range. Defined names are hidden behind the Names infrastructure, and thus are hard to debug. Worksheet ranges are easy to use, so use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may use the "Define Name" function.

1. Go to Formulas tab > Define Name in Define Name group.
2. Create a name, such as "Data". Choose the data cells, add "*2".
3. Then apply the Name to specific series values.

**I make a brief sample as following.**

Add a Name as your needs.

[image]

Then, please create a chart with Series A and Series B.

Enter `=Book1!Data` as Series values in Edit Series.

[image]

Or select the Series B, modify its formula from `=SERIES(Sheet1!$B$1,,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7,2)` to be `=SERIES(Sheet1!$B$1,,Book1!Data,2)` directly.

[image]